# MiniProfile - How to figure out what is going on in hidden space?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to figure out how to use MiniProfile to see why some webpages are going so slow.
I've added it in, and have added `Steps` around `Application_BeginRequest`, `Application_EndRequest` and around my Controllers action (in the image below that is the CanManageOrganization and GenerateTreeDataSource). But as you can see below those two methods run relatively quickly. After that there is a large gap until `GetVaryByCustomString` is called. How would I go about trying to figure out what is going on (where the time is being spent)?

My understanding is that the actual rending engine is what would be going on in that section? Am I incorrect here? Any suggestions on how I can figure out what the time in-between is spent doing?

[image: Profile results]

Comment: Is that mvc? Odd, normally I would expect miniprofiler itself to automatically show the start end of the action and view... What is the setup here? What type of action is it? which step is the action?

Comment: Yeah, its MVC 4.0. Its just a regular MVC Controller and action (using the Razor engine). I even tried a completely blank action/empty view and it was taking +2916.0 :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to install the `MiniProfiler.MVC3` NuGet which will give you more specific details about MVC. Yoju will see time spent for finding and rendering views as well.

Here's a sample of what you might see:

[image]

Remark: with the latest version of the NuGet if you are hosting your application in IIS7 Integrated pipeline mode or IIS Express locally you might need to add the following handler to the `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I previously used: NuGet `Install-Package MiniProfiler` to install mini-profiler but I did not add any handlers. I'll try adding that and see if anything changes. Thanks.

Comment: No, the handler is to fix a bug in the `MiniProfiler.MVC3` Nuget. It won't change anything in your situation. You need to uninstall the `MiniProfiler` package and install the `MiniProfiler.MVC3` package.

Comment: Thanks, using MiniProfiler.MV3 helped out a bunch. I was able to see that most of the time was being spent in the 'Find' routine. From there [this](http://community.miniprofiler.com/permalinks/61/what-does-find-actionname-represent-in-the-mvc-profiler) link helped out. So i've got a few things to try for lowering the time.

Comment: Yes, Find is slow when running in Debug mode. View locations are cached in Release mode (`debug="false"`) so you will not be incurring this slowness once you deploy your app.